# Instagram promotion redirects to white page with link: instagram.com/qp/batch_fetch_web, how to fix it?

Tags: facebook, instagram

I have an issue:
1) I created Ad in Fb Ads Manager to promote my Instagram account
2) I chose Instagram News Feed as a placement
3) The objective of my campaign is "Traffic", destination URL is instagram.com/user_name 
4) I opened preview of my ad in Instagram News Feed, I clicked the action button ("Learn more") and my account opened in instagram web browser, after few seconds I was redirected to the white page with this URL: https://www.instagram.com/qp/batch_fetch_web/.

I know that there is a "lifehack": to promote a post from Instagram account directly, but i need to create Ad in FB Ads Manager (not from my Instagram account)

So my question are:
Does anybody know how to fix this problem and promote Instagram acc through Facebook Ads Manger without this bug (my Instagam account should be opened in Instagram app not in browser(!!!))?

Comment: No! This is big issue of facebook ads! Because white screen is in every phone in every ads that we had tested. If goal of your promotion is Instagram account you will see white screen. The biggest problem is that many advertisers don't know about it. So facebook take our money but we have nothing from them, only white screen and link https://www.instagram.com/qp/batch_fetch_web/

Comment: Yep, 
I wrote to Fb support but didn't receive answer yet. Did you try to claim this problem to Fb support, did you get answers?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are seeing is likely local only to your machine.  I saw this problem in Chrome, but Firefox worked, and only for my IG account.  That led me to believe there was a cookie problem. In Chrome, I logged into my Instagram account, and the problem went away (even after logging out).  I'm led to believe that Instagram updated their site in a way that conflicts with an older-stored cookie.